# How can I calculate session IDs from event data, assigning a new ID every time there was no event for 15 minutes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a huge file with events tracked a website. The data contains, among others, the `user_id` and the `time_stamp` of events (clicked on a link, viewed an image, etc.). Here is a simplified example:

```
#%%
import pandas as pd

# make a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['123', 1],
                   ['123', 1],
                   ['123', 19],
                   ['234', 7],
                   ['234', 28],
                   ['234', 29]],
                   columns=['user_id', 'time_stamp'])
print(df)
```

What I would like to obtain is a `session_id` column, which is counting the sessions for each user. (Alternatively a string with the `user_id` and the `time_stamp` concatenated, but I assume counting is simpler?) I want it to look somewhat like this:

```
# make a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['123', 1,  0],
                   ['123', 1,  0],
                   ['123', 19, 1],
                   ['234', 7,  0],
                   ['234', 28, 1],
                   ['234', 29, 1]],
                   columns=['user_id', 'time_stamp', session_id])
print(df)
```

I read quite a lot, and tried even more, but I just can't figure out how to do it without a `for` loop. There is probably some `.shift(1)` involved and something with `.groupby()`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['session_id'] = df.groupby('user_id')['time_stamp'].diff() >= 15
df['session_id'] = df.groupby('user_id')['session_id'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  user_id  time_stamp  session_id
0     123           1           0
1     123           1           0
2     123          19           1
3     234           7           0
4     234          28           1
5     234          29           1
```

Comment: I upvoted your insightful answer, but would you explain these two lines?

Comment: @Mario The `.diff()` will make difference between all the rows. Then I compare these differences to find which is greater or equal to 15 (this will create a boolean Series). Then I do `.cumsum()` on this boolean series to make the session ID (note: False + False = 0, False + True = 1, True + True = 2)